# QEMU: Slow video performance with Windows 7 guest

Tags: performance, virtualization, fedora, qemu, libvirt

I'm running a Windows 7 guest virtualised under QEMU/virt-manager on a Fedora 17 host and video performance seems poor. Mouse movement is laggy and unresponsive.

The guest is using a qxl video adapter and a Spice display. The guest Windows 7 has the latest spice tools installed. Changing spice to VLC in virt-manager doesn't improve things, neither does switching to a different display adapter (vga/cirrus). I've tried upping video memory, also didn't help.

I'm guessing this is video related as connecting to the Windows box directly via RDP is much more responsive.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: Yeah I realised this after, if someone could migrate this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I try run qemu with win7 trough: 
1. sdl -> fbdev
2. sdl -> nouveaufb(not work for me)
3. sdl -> directfb(not work for me)
4. sdl -> ggi(mouse not work) -> fbdev(or nouveaufb)
5. sdl(with USE="opengl") -> xorg(with nouveau opengl).
It all works same) video is smoothing, no luck)